# Does continuity at every real number imply continuity over an interval?

Tags: continuity

I am trying to prove something but my proofs requires me to make the step from saying that a function $f(x)$ is continuous at all points $x \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x)$ is continuous over an interval $[x,x+\epsilon]$.

I know it may seem obvious and trivial but I just wanted a clarification on this.

Thanks!

(I know there is a similar question to this but it does not talk about when the function is continuous at every real)

Comment: What is your definition of continuity over an interval?  One common definition is simply that the function is continuous at every point of the interval...

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, good point. I guess I never said it out loud to myself.

Comment: Yes I guess it does mean the same thing